# Suggestion for encrypting data with ZeroMQ

Tags: c++, encryption, zeromq

I'm exercising with ØMQ and have developed a simple publisher/subscribers using [cppzmq](https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq) with reference to [zguide](https://github.com/booksbyus/zguide/blob/master/examples/C%2B%2B/zhelpers.hpp). Please find code snippet of the same as below, I'm able to successfully publish and subscribe data and memory footprint also quite impressive. Since this is the distributed messaging system I would like to use it in my project.

## publisher.cpp

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
//  Prepare our context and publisher
zmq::context_t context(1);
zmq::socket_t publisher(context, ZMQ_PUB);

std::string addr("tcp://*:");
addr += ((argc > 1) ? std::string(argv[1]) : "5563");
std::string tappend((argc > 2) ? std::string(argv[2]) : "");
publisher.bind(addr.c_str());

struct timeval timeofday;

for(unsigned int idx = 0; idx < Total_Topics; ++idx)
{
    Topics.emplace(std::make_pair(idx, std::string("temperature/celsius" + tappend + std::to_string(idx))));
}

std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(2));

for(unsigned int NoOfTimes = 0; NoOfTimes < 20000; ++NoOfTimes)
{
    for(unsigned int count = 0; count < Topics.size(); ++count)
    {
      {
         Quote quote = {};
         quote.ticker = "BHELL";
         gettimeofday(&timeofday,NULL);
         quote.timestampus = timeofday.tv_usec;
         quote.timestamps = timeofday.tv_sec;

         std::stringstream ss;

         quote.value *= 0.1;
         quote.data = std::to_string(NoOfTimes) + std::to_string(count);

         ss << quote;

         s_sendmore(publisher, Topics[count]);
         std::cout << "Publish "<< Topics[count] << std::endl;
         s_send(publisher, ss.str());
      }
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(8));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

## subscriber.cpp

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
//  Prepare our context and subscriber
zmq::context_t context(1);
zmq::socket_t subscriber (context, ZMQ_SUB);

std::string addr("tcp://localhost:");
addr += ((argc > 1) ? std::string(argv[1]) : "5563");
std::string tappend((argc > 2) ? std::string(argv[2]) : "");
subscriber.connect(addr.c_str());

struct timeval timeofday;

std::string topic("");

for(unsigned int idx = 0; idx < Total_Topics; ++idx)
{
    topic = std::string("temperature/celsius" + tappend + std::to_string(idx));
    subscriber.setsockopt( ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, topic.c_str(), topic.length());
}

while(1)
{
    {
        Quote quote;
        std::stringstream ss;

        std::string address = s_recv (subscriber);
        std::cout<<"Msg Rcvd" << std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Topic: " << address << std::endl;

        std::string contents = s_recv (subscriber);

        ss << contents;
        ss >> quote;

        gettimeofday(&timeofday,NULL);
        std::cout << "us diff  "  << (timeofday.tv_usec - quote.timestampus) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Sec diff "  << (timeofday.tv_sec - quote.timestamps) << std::endl;
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

Now I would like to know which security technique should be used with zeroMQ. I understand there are [curveZMQ](http://curvezmq.org/) and [czmq](https://github.com/zeromq/czmq). But I'm not sure which one should I use. Anybody already has used any of these or you have anyother libraries for ZeroMQ security. Please advise.

Comment: CurveZMQ is what you want.  czmq provides a C interface to the base ZeroMQ library (which is written in C++).  It does not provide encryption.

Comment: @colini, Thanks for shedding some light on that. I'm fairly new to zeroMQ. I totally understand that now. Do CurveZMQ has node.js bindings?. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After digging up further on the zeroMQ encryption, I found that [libcurve](https://github.com/zeromq/libcurve) (C version) and [libzmq](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq) (C++ version) supports the curve security. By default `libzmq` supports the curve and libcurve requires [libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium), libzmq, and [czmq](https://github.com/zeromq/czmq).

To find out what the difference between libcurve and libzmq curve implementation, you can through the discussion [here](https://lists.zeromq.org/pipermail/zeromq-dev/2013-September/022349.html).

Please find for sample PUB/SUB implementation with libcurve [here](https://gist.github.com/Panchatcharam/9407fc14611035a499faa4e169272668).

Comment: Does this mean that if I use libzmq in `C++` I will have security by default? I'm confused